# Android: making buttons off the view

Tags: java, android, menu, animated

I have to make complicated animated menu sliding from the top of the screen. Due to it's nature I can't use slidingDrawer... Is there any other option for it?

Comment: We'll need more details, this is a very very vague question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably accomplish this using a Canvas and Drawables. Look here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to animate a whole layout off the screen, if you supply negative parameters. This would allow you to hide a layout above or under the screen and slide it in once it is needed.